# I want to add price breakup of total amount of a product and configure the product in Magento

Tags: magento, customization, magento-1.9

I want to add price breakup of total amount of a product and configure the product in Magento.
[Click here to see image reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVaM4.png)

Anyone here who can provide me solution for the same?

Answer (score 0):

For example, we have pen option and Madison LX2200 and Madison RX3400 as it’s values. Each one of those pens is a simple product (called ‘selection‘ in admin).

Now that we have gone through the basics, we’ll create the code necessary to create a bundle product with two options – each one containing two values to represent simple products.

```
 $bundleSelections = array();
 $bundleSelections = array(
  '0' => array( //option ID
        '0' => array( //selection ID of the option (first product under this option (option ID) would have ID of 0, second an ID of 1, etc)
            'product_id' => '554', //if of a product in selection
            'delete' => '',
            'selection_price_value' => '10',
            'selection_price_type' => 0,
            'selection_qty' => 1,
            'selection_can_change_qty' => 0,
            'position' => 0,
            'is_default' => 1
        ),

        '1' => array(
            'product_id' => '553',
            'delete' => '',
            'selection_price_value' => '10',
            'selection_price_type' => 0,
            'selection_qty' => 1,
            'selection_can_change_qty' => 0,
            'position' => 0,
            'is_default' => 1
        )
    ),
```

Comment: Hi Raj, Have a look of this link http://goo.gl/PDl47m and tell me will it look like this?